# How to resolve error error C3668, C2065, C2923, C2976, C3203 in Unreal Engine 4.27 Plus

Tags: windows, sdk, visual-studio-2022, unreal-engine4, physx

I'm building the project using Unreal Engine 4.27Plus in Visual Studio 2022 in Windows 10.
I have installed the the necessary packages and SDKs still I'm getting error.

```
14>C:/Users/xyz/Desktop/dev/UE4/Engine/Source/Runtime/PhysicsCore/Private/PhysicalMaterial.cpp(92): error C2653: 'FChaosEngineInterface': is not a class or namespace name
14>C:/Users/xyz/Desktop/dev/UE4/Engine/Source/Runtime/PhysicsCore/Private/PhysicalMaterial.cpp(92): error C3861: 'ReleaseMaterial': identifier not found
14>C:/Users/xyz/Desktop/dev/UE4/Engine/Source/Runtime/PhysicsCore/Private/PhysicalMaterial.cpp(103): error C2027: use of undefined type 'FPhysicsMaterialHandle_PhysX'
14>  C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\dev\UE4\Engine\Source\Runtime\PhysicsCore\Public\PhysicsInterfaceDeclaresCore.h(188): note: see declaration of 'FPhysicsMaterialHandle_PhysX'
14>C:/Users/xyz/Desktop/dev/UE4/Engine/Source/Runtime/PhysicsCore/Private/PhysicalMaterial.cpp(103): error C2232: '->TUniquePtr<FPhysicsMaterialHandle,TDefaultDelete<T>>::IsValid': left operand has 'class' type, use '.'
14>          with
14>          [
14>              T=FPhysicsMaterialHandle
14>          ]
14>C:/Users/xyz/Desktop/dev/UE4/Engine/Source/Runtime/PhysicsCore/Private/PhysicalMaterial.cpp(105): error C2653: 'FChaosEngineInterface': is not a class or namespace name
14>C:/Users/xyz/Desktop/dev/UE4/Engine/Source/Runtime/PhysicsCore/Private/PhysicalMaterial.cpp(105): error C3861: 'CreateMaterial': identifier not found
14>C:/Users/xyz/Desktop/dev/UE4/Engine/Source/Runtime/PhysicsCore/Private/PhysicalMaterial.cpp(105): error C2582: 'operator =' function is unavailable in 'FPhysicsMaterialHandle_PhysX'
14>C:/Users/xyz/Desktop/dev/UE4/Engine/Source/Runtime/PhysicsCore/Private/PhysicalMaterial.cpp(106): error C2027: use of undefined type 'FPhysicsMaterialHandle_PhysX'
14>  C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\dev\UE4\Engine\Source\Runtime\PhysicsCore\Public\PhysicsInterfaceDeclaresCore.h(188): note: see declaration of 'FPhysicsMaterialHandle_PhysX'
14>C:/Users/xyz/Desktop/dev/UE4/Engine/Source/Runtime/PhysicsCore/Private/PhysicalMaterial.cpp(106): error C2232: '->TUniquePtr<FPhysicsMaterialHandle,TDefaultDelete<T>>::IsValid': left operand has 'class' type, use '.'
14>          with
14>          [
14>              T=FPhysicsMaterialHandle
14>          ]
14>C:/Users/xyz/Desktop/dev/UE4/Engine/Source/Runtime/PhysicsCore/Private/PhysicalMaterial.cpp(108): error C2653: 'FChaosEngineInterface': is not a class or namespace name
14>C:/Users/xyz/Desktop/dev/UE4/Engine/Source/Runtime/PhysicsCore/Private/PhysicalMaterial.cpp(108): error C3861: 'SetUserData': identifier not found
14>C:/Users/xyz/Desktop/dev/UE4/Engine/Source/Runtime/PhysicsCore/Private/PhysicalMaterial.cpp(109): error C2653: 'FChaosEngineInterface': is not a class or namespace name
14>C:/Users/xyz/Desktop/dev/UE4/Engine/Source/Runtime/PhysicsCore/Private/PhysicalMaterial.cpp(109): error C3861: 'UpdateMaterial': identifier not found
```

I have tried solutions mentioned in

https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/building-ue-4-27-fails-due-to-missing-physx-headers-on-microsoft-windows/484568/49

For this solution  https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/ue-4-27-build-failed/632549

I downloaded the SDK unzipped and added the path “C:\PhysX-105.0-physx-5.2.1\physx\include\foundation” in Project Pages-> VC++ directories-> include.
Am I doing something wrong? Please guide me. Thanks